# Link or javascript to trigger media (audio) share in mobile browser

Tags: audio, web, share, whatsapp

I'm looking for a way to create a button that, when clicked, triggers the share menu in a phone (it doesn't have to work on a PC) in order to send an audio file (eventually) to a Whatsapp conversation.

Meaning that touching a button in a web page (if you're on your phone) will trigger a screen that will let yo select whatsapp, and then a conversation and share an audio file like when long pressing to share a link (but instead sent the audio file to the selected conversation).

After some research I'm quite empty handed, there only seems to be a paid Business API from Whatsapp, but this seems to be for more than what I'm only actually looking for. I've also found something called [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) but couldn't find any example or implementation.

Thanks for your help,